# SQL Script Command Line Arguments

Tags: sql-server, command-line, sqlcmd

Is there a way to get a script file that will be executing via SQLCMD to accept the parms passed in the SQLCMD call..

ie..

SQLCMD (assume the connection is OK..) -V "1/25/2012" -i "ScriptFile.sql"

What would the structure of ScriptFile.sql Look like? Would it start with the same as any other procedure..?

Basically I'm trying to call a text file script with parameters as an SQL command.  So far I haven't been able to find any MSDN articles on this one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK.. If anyone cares, it Goes Like This...

The SQL Script file which is using the variable uses the variable like so:

Update TableName Set ColumnValue=$(Param)

--Notice there's no declare,  and the format of the parameter uses
     $(Param) instead of @Param as a variable...

The Command line looks almost the same.  For some reason, the passed value needs to be in single quotes within double quotes, like so:

SQLCMD -S ServerName -d DatabaseName -v Param="'Param'" -i"ScriptFile.sql"

Use just double quotes around the ScriptFile name, Single within Double for the Parameters.

Comment: Would it work to have `Set ColumnValue='$(Param)'` in your script and then pass the value without the single quotes?

Comment: @CoderDennis it does work like that also. Just tested it.

Answer (score 1):

USE:

```
sqlcmd -E -S <Your Server> -v test="Test String" -i file.sql
```

file.sql:

```
SELECT @test
```

Comment: Retraction.. It appeared to work.. Till I chased it all the way thru..  It's not passing the parm.. I can include samples of everything.. Watching the profiler, I can see the SQL is executing but the Parm has no value.. It's updating the DB with a null value..

Answer (score 1):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx you can use -v to set a scripting variable. This worked for me, and the other solutions here didnt;

prune.sql:
**delete from Table where Column=$(Param)**

and in dos cmd or in powershell:
**sqlcmd -S "My Server" -v Param=100 -i prune.sql**

Quotation marks seem only to be needed when the value being set has spaces. Hope this helps.