# how to execute .sql files with parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hello is it possible to run .sql file with parameter

like

```
:R c:\scripts\<scrips1>.sql,<param>
:R c:\scripts\<scrips2>.sql,<param>
```

Comment: Where are you trying to "execute" these from?  .SQL files open in SQL Server Management Studio where you can execute them there; they don't execute outside of that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010359/sql-script-command-line-arguments

Comment: @roryap you can execute them from a command line.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
sqlcmd -E -S <Server name> -v test="Some value" -i YourSqlFile.sql
```

Also check [Use sqlcmd with Scripting Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx)